# Arrays - foreach brings ->Fatal error: Cannot use object of type

Tags: php

So, I'm mad about this Arrays, 2nd day givin me pain in ***....

I'm developing an OOP PHP script.

I'm getting an array:

```
Array ( [0] => Project Object ( [project_id] => 1 [title] => Some Name [date] => 2011-10-20 [place] => Some City [customer] => 1 [proj_budget] => [manager] => 1 [team] => 1 [currency] => 1 ) )
```

When I'm trying to do this:

```
<?php
    $project = new Project();
    $projects = $project->findAll();
    print_r($projects);
    foreach ($projects as $temptwo) {
      echo $temptwo['title'].", \n";
    }
?>
```

I'm getting this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Project as array
```

Why in the world? what does it want from me?

Comment: Yeah friendly manual - I agree.. and thanks guys for your answers, I know how to use $project->title, and that's what I did couple of minutes ago but it didn't work.. Thanks all of you for your reply..

It didn't work then, now I tried - it work, I'll crush my laptop... :D 

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9):

You access the items as arrays

```
echo $temptwo['title'].", \n";
```

You probably want to access their properties

```
echo $temptwo->title.", \n";
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are looping an array of objects, so each item in your array is an object you'll need to address as an object.

```
foreach($projects as $temptwo){
    echo $temptwo->title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It wants you to use the object as an object, not an array.

```
    echo $temptwo->title . ", \n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
echo $temptwo->title.", \n";
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You try to get the data of object. It seems as an array but it is not. it is an object so you have to use

$temptwo->title