# Date/Time Object from JSON to PHP Foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, datetime

I have a tried numerous examples on stack already and I cant seem to get this right! I am trying to pull the date from this DateTime Object also the reason for the two lines of time was because I was trying different methods and compare the return.

```
[created] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-06-06 15:22:25.720000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +00:00
                )
```

but for some reason i'm getting the completely wrong date and time.

```
19-09-04 22:37:18
1970-01-01 01:00:00

19-09-04 22:37:18
1970-01-01 01:00:00

19-09-04 22:37:18
1970-01-01 01:00:00

19-09-04 22:37:18
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

I've tried the following:
[JSON Array to PHP DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271865/json-array-to-php-datetime)
[PHP date time from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372736/php-date-time-from-string)
[Arrays - foreach brings ->Fatal error: Cannot use object of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463954/arrays-foreach-brings-fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type)

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
    $vPaccomments = $issue->fields->comment->comments;

    foreach ($vPaccomments as $vPaccomment) {
        $vPacAvatarUrl = $vPaccomment->author->avatarUrls;
        $size16 = "16x16";
        $vPacCreated = $vPaccomment->created;
        $vPacDate = $vPacCreated->date;
        $vPacDateConv = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($vPacDate));

        $dateTime = new DateTime($vPacDate);
        echo $dateTime->format('y-m-d H:i:s');

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($vPacDateConv);

        echo "<div class=\"col\">";
        //echo "<img width=\"16px\" src=\"" . $vPacAvatarUrl[$size16] . "\"> " . "<font color=\"#0015ff\">" .$vPaccomment->author->displayName ."</font> added a comment - " . date_format($vPacCreateDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');    
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

?>
```

If I `echo '<pre>'; print_r($vPacCreated);`

I get the correct results i want to grab

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-06 15:22:25.720000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-07 13:58:31.970000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-17 14:07:23.040000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-17 14:25:13.840000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

Here is the portion of the values:

```
 [comment] => JiraRestApi\Issue\Comments Object
        (
            [startAt] => 0
            [maxResults] => 4
            [total] => 4
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => JiraRestApi\Issue\Comment Object
                        (
                            [self] => https://xxx/rest/api/2/xxx
                            [id] => xxx
                            [author] => JiraRestApi\Issue\Reporter Object
                                (
                                    [self] => https://xxx/rest/api/2/xxx
                                    [name] => xxx
                                    [emailAddress] => xxx
                                    [avatarUrls] => Array
                                        (
                                            [48x48] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?avatarId=xxx
                                            [24x24] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=xxx
                                            [16x16] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=xxx
                                            [32x32] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=xxx
                                        )

                                    [displayName] => xxx
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [wantUnassigned:JiraRestApi\Issue\Reporter:private] => 
                                    [accountId] => 
                                    [key] => xxx
                                    [timeZone] => America/New_York
                                )

                            [body] => xxx

CREATED ON:6/6/2019

COPIED TO:\\xxx
                            [updateAuthor] => JiraRestApi\Issue\Reporter Object
                                (
                                    [self] => https://xxx/rest/api/2/xxx
                                    [name] => xxx
                                    [emailAddress] => xxx
                                    [avatarUrls] => Array
                                        (
                                            [48x48] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?avatarId=xxx
                                            [24x24] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=xxx
                                            [16x16] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=xxx
                                            [32x32] => https://xxx/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=xxx
                                        )

                                    [displayName] => xxx
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [wantUnassigned:JiraRestApi\Issue\Reporter:private] => 
                                    [accountId] => 
                                    [key] => xxx
                                    [timeZone] => America/New_York
                                )

                            [created] => DateTime Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 2019-06-06 15:22:25.720000
                                    [timezone_type] => 1
                                    [timezone] => +00:00
                                )
```

Comment: It seems from your question that `$vPacCreated` is already a `DateTime` object, so you should be able to just `echo $vPacCreated->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: You get dates like this `1970-01-01` when there is an error in the date you are trying to set

Comment: @Nick you are the man!!!!! Thank you so much that worked please set as the answer so i can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your input data, it looks like `$vPacCreated` is already a `DateTime` object, so you should be able to just

```
echo $vPacCreated->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks I was pulling my hair out on this one!